# Add PySpark column based on dictionary where the keys are tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I have the following python dictionary:

```
ranges = {
    (0, 10): '0 - 10',
    (10, 100): '10 - 100',
    (100, float('inf')): '100+'
}
```

And the following df:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 9 |
| 002 | 10 |
| 003 | 300 |

I would like to add a column that returns the dictionary's value if the "Value" column is between (exclusive) the two numbers in the dictionary's key.

So resulting df should look like this:

| Id | Value | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 9 | 0 - 10 |
| 002 | 10 | 10 - 100 |
| 003 | 300 | 100+ |

I know I can use withColumn and when, e.g.:

```
df.withColumn(
    'Range',
     .when((col('Value') >= lit(0)) & (col('Value') < lit(10)), '0 - 10')
)
```

and so on, but it would be inefficient if I have 100s of key-value pairs or wanted to test with different numbers in the keys.

Hopefully this makes sense. I would appreciate any and all inputs. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary can be transformed into an SQL expression:

```python
range_expr='case '
for r, label  in ranges.items():
    range_expr += f'when value >= {r[0]} '
    if r[1] != float('inf'):
      range_expr += f'and value < {r[1]} '
    range_expr += f'then "{label}" '
range_expr += 'end'
```

`range_expr` has now the value

```sql
case when value >= 0 and value < 10 then "0 - 10" when value >= 10 and value < 100 then "10 - 100" when value >= 100 then "100+" end
```

and can be used to construct a new column:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('range', F.expr(range_expr)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
| id|value|   range|
+---+-----+--------+
|001|    9|  0 - 10|
|002|   10|10 - 100|
|003|  300|    100+|
+---+-----+--------+
```